# Can I avoid screen from creating inner screens?

Tags: gnu-screen

I just started using screen and "screen inception" makes learning screen even more confusing. Can I avoid screen from creating screens when I'm already inside a screen?

[image]

I'm using [fish](http://fishshell.com/) as my shell if that matters.

Comment: Yes you can, check the `STY` environment variable - http://web.mit.edu/gnu/doc/html/screen_20.html